# Is there any literature that proofs that printf's %f converts float to double?

Tags: c, standards, c99, c89, ansi-c

I've read that printf's %f specifier is used for double and that it automatically converts float to double. But I couldn't find any proof in books (though it's stated on the web).

I don't have access to a copy of the ANSI C standard files and I couldn't find the specific place in the glibc source code. I have searched in "The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition".

I need to have something for ANSI C specifically.

As effeffe pointed out, there is a paragraph in the C89 standard, 3.3.2.2 which states what I was looking for. In C99 it's just a different paragraph.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong thing - it's not printf that does the conversion. It's argument promotion that happens for functions with `...` arguments. The answer in the linked question has a link to a draft C standard you can check.

Comment: @Mat: How does that answer his question specifically?  Are you saying that his premise is wrong, and that `%f` is merely a formatting specifier, which doesn't change the underlying data type?  If that is true, then why are you pointing him to something that has no relevance?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: yes, `%f` is purely formatting. printf receives its arguments already promoted (float to double, small ints to int). The linked question affirms that, and that it is standard-mandated behavior, with a link to said standard.

Comment: To be clear, does `printf` promote the float argument to a double *because* the `%f` is specified, or does it merely display it in the float form?

Comment: @Mat that's a C99 draft. I have found this: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.2.2.1 but it's different from the C99.

Comment: @ctwx: Probably because that's C89.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: `printf` doesn't receive a float at all, it receives a double.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's why I asked. I can't take the C99 draft as a source when talking about ANSI C. So I am searching for papers, books or something that states something similar.

Comment: Sounds like you need to purchase the actual specification.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OK thanks. That's at least a start. I hoped that there'd be something anybody can access. Thanks!

Comment: The linked answer refers to C99 6.5.2.2 "Function calls": C89 describes the same behavior in a section with the same title, it just has a different number, 3.3.2.2...

Comment: @Ctwx: if you need an inexpensive official copy of a C or C++ standard document, I try to track those in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/83763/12711  However, keep in mind that [the standard committee says this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards.html) about [WG14 N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf): "The latest publicly available version of the C99 standard is the combined C99 + TC1 + TC2 + TC3, WG14 N1256, dated 2007-09-07. This is a WG14 working paper, **but it reflects the consolidated standard at the time of issue**"

Answer (score 1):

It's not the printf function .Default argument promotion in functions with variable parameters uses a temporary double variable ,initialized with the float that you pass in , causing the floats to be treated like doubles.

In the variable-length part of a variable-length argument list, the ``default argument promotions'' apply: types char and short int are promoted to int, and float is promoted to double.

References: ISO Sec. 6.3.2.2 
H&S Sec. 6.3.5 p. 177, Sec. 9.4 pp. 272-3

C Standard. Chapter 6.5.2.2.

Comment: Do you have an authoritative reference for this behavior?

Comment: He asked for literature (read: official citations), not for facts, so this is unfortunately not an answer.

Comment: fixed . see the references .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the description of printf and the format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf).

It lists `f` to be used for decimal floating point. It doesn't say whether it is appropriate for `float` or `double`.

A little ways down, there is a table in that page that describes the length sub-specifier, such as `%lf`. It shows:

[image: lengh sub-specifiers]

Adding the `l` sub-specifier does not change the meaning of `%f`. It also indicates that `%f` is used  for `double`s not `float`s. Conversion of a `float` to a `double` is implied from this.

Comment: This sort of dances around the problem.  Yes, the promotion is implied, but not specifically stated.

Comment: Noting that `%lf` was added C99; in C90 it caused undefined behaviour.